Screen went blank when installing Ubuntu Studio 24.04 on a specific hard drive
I have been installing Ubuntu Studio 24.04 on a few desktop computers (HP, varying models from 2013-14) to create a dual boot set-ups with Windows 10. Two of them cannot boot from the USB, so I tried to move the hard drive to a different computer and perform the installation there. The first one went smoothly, but when trying to install the ubuntu on a second hard drive, as usual I got the "Try Ubuntu" menu, but then the screen went blank. Safe graphics does not work either (it went blank as well).
The hard drive is a Toshiba, an identical model with the first one (which get the ubuntu installed smoothly). It already has a working Windows 10 partition, and it can boot from any computer. The live USB definitely work (I tried it again with another hard drive on the same PC, and it worked). So only this particular hard drive caused the live USB to fail. I tried to use it as a second hard drive, and still, I cannot boot from the live USB (although I can boot from the first hard drive and mount the problematic one)
I don't really know what can I do next to continue. Any help, direction, or idea will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
